# search for file, when found in particular folder, move that folder to another location

Tags: powershell

I need help to be able to search on target folder for `lastrefresh.xml` file with last modified date older than 180 days. If it finds this file being older, whole folder where this XML file sits should be moved to archive path to another destination path.

```
$targetfolder = "\\something\*\*\*\*\*\files\files\
$archivefolder = "\\something\*\*\archive\
```

I'm using below script to have this working for folders, where it checks modified date of folder and this works.

```
$targetfolder = "\\something\*\*\*\*\*\files\files\
$archivefolder = "\\something\*\*\archive\

$LastWrite = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)

$Files = Get-ChildItem $TargetFolder |
         Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -le $LastWrite} |
         Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName |
         ForEach-Object {
           write-host "Archiving following folder" $_ $ArchiveFolder1
           Move-Item $_ $ArchiveFolder
         }
```

But how could I have similar to above, where I only need to check for `LastRefresh.xml` files modified date in all targetfolder subfolders, and if it match my `$lastwrite` parameter for that XML file it would move whole folder with that file and all other files in that folder where it was found.

I only need to be able to check `lastrefresh.xml` files data modified. If it is older than 180 days, move whole folder where this XML file is present. This file is present in many folders.

Comment: The code sample you posted is invalid. Please fix it. Also, is it possible that folders with a file `lastrefresh.xml` contain other folders with a file `lastrefresh.xml`?

Comment: i have updated the one im using for folders. The lastrefresh.xml file is in the many folder but inside the folder of lastrefresh.xml, there are no other folder. So folder/folder/lastrefresh.xml with other xml files. Folder/folder1/lastrefresh.xml, folder/folder2/lastrefresh.xml and etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```psh
Get-ChildItem $TargetFolder -File | ? {
  $_.Name -eq 'lastrefresh.xml' -and $_.LastWriteTime -le $LastWrite
} | % {
  Move-Item $_.Directory "$ArchiveFolder\"
}
```

Comment: This is good improvement, it seems it is almost working! if i place lastrefresh.xml into the main folder it works, but i have many folders in that main folder and in these folders basically i have lastrefresh.xml.files. folder/folder1/lastrefresh.xml. folder/folder2/lastrefresh.xml. If i place lastrefresh.xml into the folder/lastrefresh.xml it works. If it is in folder/folder1/lastrefresh.xml it doesnt. i tried to add \*\ into the $TargetFolder at end of my defined path, but it still doesn't give any results. $targetfolder = "\\something\bla\bla\folder\*\

Comment: I got it working by adding $targetfolder = "\\something\bla\bla\folder\*\*" two * seperated by backward slash at end of targetfolder path. Thanks Ansgar for your time helping me!